# Qt: invalid use of incomplete type and forward declaration

Tags: c++, qt

I have some misunderstanding:

A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "B.h"

class A : public B
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    A();
};
#endif
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
A::A()
{
    B::ui->blancH2->setValue(2);
}
```

B.h

```
#include <QWidget>
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

namespace Ui {
    class B;
}
class B
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit B(QWidget *parent = 0);

public:
    Ui::B *ui;
};

#endif
```

As result of compiling I have next errors:
A.cpp: In constructor 'A::A()': invalid use of incomplete type 'class Ui::B'
B.h: forward declaration of 'class Ui::B'

Can anybody explain why I have this errors?

Comment: Tip: B and Ui::B are not the same class. They are totally different.

Comment: You have two different classes called B here, Ui::B and just B.  Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: as Mike Seymour noticed, you should include in a.cpp file same header, which is included in b.cpp, which contains definition of `Ui::B` class.

Answer (score 15):

Check you ui_B.h. At the end of it, you should see

```
namespace Ui {
    class B: public Ui_B {};
}
```

If it's not, you can open you .ui file in Qt Designer, select your widget, and in Object Inspector, change the string under 'Object' to 'B'. The default value is 'Dialog' if your widget is a dialog.

Don't modify ui_B.h directly since it's generated by Qt compiler and it will be overwritten every time you compile.

Comment: Yes.. I come to this kind of error, finally it was because earlier I rename the class name but fogot to update in .ui's object name of this UI, thus the name was not auto generated correctly.

Comment: This looks more like an oversight on Qt's part. When creating a new class and a new ui file for a form, it proposes form.ui as the filename, but if I specify a different filename, the name of the object will still be "Form"

Comment: Had to restart Qt creator after ensuring what you said, not sure why though. Massive thumbs up!

Answer (score 11):

As the error says, there is no definition of `Ui::B` available, only the declaration in `B.h`; and you can't write code that accesses members of a class unless the class has been defined.

You need to include whichever header defines `Ui::B`; or, perhaps, give `B` a member function to do whatever `A` needs doing, rather than furtling with `B`'s members directly.

Answer (score 5):

In Qt Creator, open the dialog form.  Select the dialog panel and on the right be sure that the Object Name is B.

That will let the Qt build system know that your object is a UI object.  Without this, your program only knows your panel as an object name Dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I met this problem when I've changed the name of 'MainWindow' to 'LoginWindow' after the whole app is established.This can't be useful for everyone but change the name of it to the original one(which you filled in when start the project) can work for me. 
Still don't know about .ui files of Qt hoping anyone can explain this~

Comment: Also, you can change in *.ui file by another editor (not QtCreator) the class field and the main widget name. This will solve your problem.