# Connecting Signals and Slots between Child and Parent (invalid use of incomplete type)

Tags: qt

I'm trying to connect signals from a child window (`QDialog` named `VolumePage`) to its parent (`QMainWindow` named `MockUI`). I'm running into a:

> invalid use of incomplete type 'class Ui::VolumePage'

error when I attempt to make the connection.

I'm trying to connect inside the MockUI.cpp when I make the volume page. (Happens on a button press)

```
 void MockUI::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
 {
 //Non-Modal Approach

 volPage = new VolumePage(this); 
 volPage->show();
 connect(volPage->ui->verticalSlider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),ui->progressBar,SLOT(setValue(int)));
 }
```

I've made `Ui::VolumePage *ui;` public.

Here's the entire error:

> error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Ui::VolumePage' 
>       connect(volPage->ui->verticalSlider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),ui->progressBar,SLOT(setValue(int)));

Can anyone help me understand what the problem is, or another clean way to do what I'm trying to do?

**Edit:**  (Additional Source)

VolumePage.h:

```
#ifndef VOLUMEPAGE_H
#define VOLUMEPAGE_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class VolumePage;
}

class VolumePage : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit VolumePage(QWidget *parent = 0);
    Ui::VolumePage *ui;
    ~VolumePage();

private slots:
    void on_verticalSlider_valueChanged(int value);

private:

};

#endif // VOLUMEPAGE_H
```

mockUI.cpp:

```
#include "mockUI.h"
#include "ui_mock_ics.h"
#include <QLCDNumber>
#include "volumepage.h"

MockUI::MockUI(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MockUI)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MockUI::~MockUI()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MockUI::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    //Modal Approach
    //VolumePage volPage;
    //volPage.setModal(true);
    //volPage.exec();

    //Non-Modal Approach
    volPage = new VolumePage(this);    
    volPage->show();
    connect(volPage->ui->verticalSlider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),ui->progressBar,SLOT(setValue(int)));

}
```

volumepage.cpp:

```
#include "volumepage.h"
#include "mockUI.h"
#include "ui_volumepage.h"

VolumePage::VolumePage(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::VolumePage)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::Popup);
    //Mock_ICS* ics = (Mock_ICS*)parent;
    //connect(ui->verticalSlider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),ics->ui->progressBar,SLOT(setValue(int)));
    //connect(ui->verticalSlider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),this->parent()->progressBar,SLOT(setValue(int)));


}

VolumePage::~VolumePage()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ui::VolumePage *ui` should remain private. Instead create a signal on the volPage, something like `verticalSliderValueChanged(int value)`. See below...

### mockui.h

```
#ifndef MOCKUI_H
#define MOCKUI_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "volumepage.h"

namespace Ui {
class MockUI;
}

class MockUI : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MockUI(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MockUI();
    VolumePage* volPage;

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_3_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MockUI *ui;
};

#endif // MOCKUI_H
```

### mockui.cpp

```
#include "mockui.h"
#include "ui_mockui.h"
#include "volumepage.h"

MockUI::MockUI(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MockUI)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MockUI::~MockUI()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MockUI::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    //Non-Modal Approach
    volPage = new VolumePage(this);
    volPage->show();
    connect(volPage,SIGNAL(verticalSliderValueChanged(int)),ui->progressBar,SLOT(setValue(int)));

}
```

### volumepage.h

```
#ifndef VOLUMEPAGE_H
#define VOLUMEPAGE_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class VolumePage;
}

class VolumePage : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit VolumePage(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~VolumePage();

signals:
    void verticalSliderValueChanged(int value);

private slots:
    void on_verticalSlider_valueChanged(int value);

private:
    Ui::VolumePage *ui;
};

#endif // VOLUMEPAGE_H
```

### volumepage.cpp

```
#include "volumepage.h"
#include "ui_volumepage.h"

VolumePage::VolumePage(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::VolumePage)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

VolumePage::~VolumePage()
{
    delete ui;
}

void VolumePage::on_verticalSlider_valueChanged(int value)
{
    emit verticalSliderValueChanged(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer.   There appear to be other ways to do this - but this answer looks like the cleanest way to adapt what Qt Creator auto-generates to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of the [pImpl idiom](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) in C++. Class `VolumePage` is the one you should be using - this is the "public" interface of what Qt Creator has generated. `Ui::VolumePage` contains the complicated details you should not worry about.

So, in your code you should be using `VolumePage`, not `Ui::VolumePage`. You shouldn't have make `Ui::VolumePage` public.

Comment: #include "volumepage.h" is at the start of mockUI.cpp  - Is there something more I need to do?

Comment: @josh.spickes Perhaps you are also missing the `widgets` module inclusion in your project file?

Comment: Show the volumepage.h and relevant part of mockUI.cpp - the problem seems to be there. From what you say they do not contain a complete definition of the type you're trying to connect to.

Comment: @BartoszKP Added the source.  Hope that's more clear.

Comment: 90% of this code is auto generated by Qt Creator.   I recognize that it's odd to have Ui::VolumePage and VolumePage share the same name when they are really completely different things.   That's just what Qt Creator spits out using default settings.  I think that there's some work getting done in the 'ui->setupUi(this);' call that I'm not understanding.  It must be populating the UI elements in that call.

Comment: @josh.spickes Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113581/qt-invalid-use-of-incomplete-type-and-forward-declaration ?

Comment: @josh.spickes Also, I've rewritten the answer. Please check if this helps.

Comment: @BartoszKP Appreciate the updated answer.   I think what you're proposing is something I might follow if I were not using Qt Creator.   Mark's answer fits with the Qt Creator output exactly.

Comment: @josh.spickes My answer is in essence the same, but of course my first version was too much of a guess, and Mark got it right from the beginning :)